# Add a column value with the other date time column at minutes level in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID      ideal_appt_time            service_time
1       2020-01-06 09:00:00        22
2       2020-01-06 09:30:00        15
1       2020-01-08 14:00:00        42
2       2020-01-12 01:30:00        5
```

I would like to add service time in terms of minutes with ideal_appt_time and create new column called finish.

Expected Output:

```
ID      ideal_appt_time            service_time       finish
1       2020-01-06 09:00:00        22                 2020-01-06 09:22:00
2       2020-01-06 09:30:00        15                 2020-01-06 09:45:00
1       2020-01-08 14:00:00        42                 2020-01-08 14:42:00
2       2020-01-12 01:30:00        35                 2020-01-12 02:05:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert column to timedeltas by minutes and add to datetimes:

```
df['ideal_appt_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ideal_appt_time'])

df['finish'] = df['ideal_appt_time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['service_time'], unit='Min')
print (df)
   ID     ideal_appt_time  service_time              finish
0   1 2020-01-06 09:00:00            22 2020-01-06 09:22:00
1   2 2020-01-06 09:30:00            15 2020-01-06 09:45:00
2   1 2020-01-08 14:00:00            42 2020-01-08 14:42:00
3   2 2020-01-12 01:30:00             5 2020-01-12 01:35:00
```

Comment: if u have time.. pls look into this.. nobody answered.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306761/create-new-rows-based-specific-condition-and-iterate-over-a-list-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ideal_appt_time':['2020-01-06 09:00:00','2020-01-06 09:30:00','2020-01-08 14:00:00','2020-01-12 01:30:00'],'service_time':[22,15,42,35]})
```

Another way out

```
df['finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ideal_appt_time']).add( df['service_time'].astype('timedelta64[m]'))
df

    ideal_appt_time service_time    finish
0   2020-01-06 09:00:00 22  2020-01-06 09:22:00
1   2020-01-06 09:30:00 15  2020-01-06 09:45:00
2   2020-01-08 14:00:00 42  2020-01-08 14:42:00
3   2020-01-12 01:30:00 35  2020-01-12 02:05:00
```