# create new rows based specific condition and iterate over a list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as shown below

```
B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.4   
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.7      
    3     0.8       S1        3       1.5        
    4     0.3       S1        4       1.8       
    5     0.6       S1        5       2.4         
    6     0.8       S1        6       3.2       
    7     0.9       S1        7       4.1        
    8     0.4       S1        8       4.5   
    9     0.6       S1        9       5.1     
    12    0.9       S2        1       0.9    
    13    0.5       S2        2       1.4       
    14    0.3       S2        3       1.7        
    15    0.7       S2        4       2.4         
    20    0.7       S2        5       3.1          
    16    0.6       S2        6       3.7       
    17    0.8       S2        7       4.5        
    19    0.3       S2        8       4.8
```

The code to create above df is shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'B_ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,20,16,17,19],
                   'No_Show': [0.4,0.3,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.6,0.8,0.3],
                   'Session': ['s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2'],
                   'slot_num': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   })
df['Cumulative_no_show'] = df.groupby(['Session'])['No_Show'].cumsum()
```

and a list called walkin_no_show = [ 0.3, 0.4,  0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4 and so on with length 1000]

From the above when ever u_cumulative > 0.8 create a new row just below that with

```
 df[No_Show] = walkin_no_show[i]
```

and its Session and slot_num should be same as previous one and create a new column called u_cumulative by subtracting (1 - walkin_no_show[i])  from the previous.

Expected Output:

```
B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show    u_cumulative
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.4                 0.4
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.7                 0.7
    3     0.8       S1        3       1.5                 1.5
walkin1   0.3       S1        3       1.5                 0.8
    4     0.3       S1        4       1.8                 1.1      
walkin2   0.4       S1        4       1.8                 0.5
    5     0.6       S1        5       2.4                 1.1    
walkin3   0.3       S1        5       2.4                 0.4
    6     0.8       S1        6       3.2                 1.2      
walkin4   0.4       S1        6       3.2                 0.6
    7     0.9       S1        7       4.1                 1.5               
walkin5   0.3       S1        7       4.1                 0.8   
    8     0.4       S1        8       4.5                 1.2
walkin6   0.4       S1        8       4.5                 0.6
    9     0.6       S1        9       5.1                 1.2
    12    0.9       S2        1       0.9                 0.9
walkin1   0.3       S2        1       0.9                 0.2
    13    0.5       S2        2       1.4                 0.7           
    14    0.3       S2        3       1.7                 1.0
walkin2   0.4       S2        3       1.7                 0.4
    15    0.7       S2        4       2.4                 1.1
walkin3   0.3       S2        4       2.4                 0.4      
    20    0.7       S2        5       3.1                 1.1
walkin4   0.4       S2        5       3.1                 0.5       
    16    0.6       S2        6       3.7                 1.1
walkin5   0.3       S2        6       3.7                 0.4                    
    17    0.8       S2        7       4.5                 1.2
walkin6   0.4       S2        7       4.5                 0.6       
    19    0.3       S2        8       4.8                 0.9
```

I tried below code minor edit. As answered by @Ben.T on the below mentioned my question.

[create new rows based the values of one of the column in pandas or numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441460/create-new-rows-based-the-values-of-one-of-the-column-in-pandas-or-numpy/61446490#61446490)

Thanks @Ben.T. Full credit to you..

```
def create_u_columns (ser):
    l_index = []
    arr_ns = ser.to_numpy()
    # array for latter insert
    arr_idx = np.zeros(len(ser), dtype=int)
    walkin_id = 1
    for i in range(len(arr_ns)-1):
        if arr_ns[i]>0.8:
            # remove 1 to u_no_show
            arr_ns[i+1:] -= (1-walkin_no_show[arr_idx])
            # increment later idx to add
            arr_idx[i] = walkin_id
            walkin_id +=1
    #return a dataframe with both columns
    return pd.DataFrame({'u_cumulative': arr_ns, 'mask_idx':arr_idx}, index=ser.index)

df[['u_cumulative', 'mask_idx']]= df.groupby(['Session']['Cumulative_no_show'].apply(create_u_columns)


# select the rows
df_toAdd = df.loc[df['mask_idx'].astype(bool), :].copy()
# replace the values as wanted
df_toAdd['No_Show'] = walkin_no_show[mask_idx]
df_toAdd['B_ID'] = 'walkin'+df_toAdd['mask_idx'].astype(str)
df_toAdd['u_cumulative'] -= 1
# add 0.5 to index for later sort
df_toAdd.index += 0.5 

new_df_0.8 = pd.concat([df,df_toAdd]).sort_index()\
           .reset_index(drop=True).drop('mask_idx', axis=1)
```

Also I would like to iterarate over a list. where we can change (arr_ns[i]>0.8) [0.8, 0.9, 1.0] and create 3 df such as new_df_0.8, new_df_0.9 and new_df_1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do it this way:

```
def create_u_columns (ser, threshold_ns = 0.8):

    arr_ns = ser.to_numpy()
    # array for latter insert
    arr_idx = np.zeros(len(ser), dtype=int)
    walkin_id = 0 #start at 0 not 1 for list indexing
    for i in range(len(arr_ns)-1):
        if arr_ns[i]>threshold_ns:
            # remove 1 to u_no_show
            arr_ns[i+1:] -= (1-walkin_no_show[walkin_id]) #this is slightly different
            # increment later idx to add
            arr_idx[i] = walkin_id+1
            walkin_id +=1
    #return a dataframe with both columns
    return pd.DataFrame({'u_cumulative': arr_ns, 'mask_idx':arr_idx}, index=ser.index)

#create empty dict for storing the dataframes
d_dfs = {}
#iterate over the value for the threshold
for th_ns in [0.8, 0.9, 1.0]:
    #create a copy and do the same kind of operation
    df_ = df.copy()
    df_[['u_cumulative', 'mask_idx']]= \
        df_.groupby(['Session'])['Cumulative_no_show']\
           .apply(lambda x: create_u_columns(x, threshold_ns=th_ns))

    # select the rows
    df_toAdd = df_.loc[df_['mask_idx'].astype(bool), :].copy()
    # replace the values as wanted
    df_toAdd['No_Show'] = np.array(walkin_no_show)[df_toAdd.groupby('Session').cumcount()] 
    df_toAdd['B_ID'] = 'walkin'+df_toAdd['mask_idx'].astype(str)
    df_toAdd['u_cumulative'] -= (1 - df_toAdd['No_Show'])
    # add 0.5 to index for later sort
    df_toAdd.index += 0.5 

    d_dfs[th_ns] = pd.concat([df_,df_toAdd]).sort_index()\
                       .reset_index(drop=True).drop('mask_idx', axis=1)
```

Then if you want to have access to the dataframes, you can do for example:

```
for th, df_ in d_dfs.items():
    print (th)
    print (df_.head(4))
```

Comment: can you pls share your output.. I have added the code to create input data set..
I am getting slightly different output than expected.

Comment: code for creating input data is given below.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'B_ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,20,16,17,19],
                   'No_Show': [0.4,0.3,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.6,0.8,0.3],
                   'Session': ['s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s1','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2','s2'],
                   'slot_num': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   })
df['Cumulative_no_show'] = df.groupby(['Session'])['No_Show'].cumsum()

Comment: Yes, you are correct.. It is my bad.. sorry for that.. But the output I am getting is NaN values on the u_cumulative columns.. Pls share your output..

Comment: if you have time, pls look into below question. similar to above question with small variation..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408422/create-a-function-to-create-new-rows-in-data-frames-based-on-the-given-parameter

Comment: is the question from the above question is complicated? It is very difficult to solve for me.

Comment: @Danish I think it will be a bit harder because you can have several walkin rows at once. (like walkin 4 and 5) for the threshold of 0.8. and this method does not allow this

Comment: is it possible if we add only one walkin at once that solution also looks good.. as your previous solution. If it is possible I can edit my expected output.

Comment: @Danish wait and see if someone else has another approach with your current expected output. And I'll think about it on my side :)

Comment: @Danish Also could you delete some of your previous comments, the one from june 11 are not relevant anymore as the answer has been modified to fix the error. Thsi will help to keep the site clean :)

Comment: Sure, I will delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216072/discussion-between-danish-and-ben-t).

Answer (score 1):

The only trick that you have to consider is the way you increase the index values.
Here is a solution:

walkin_no_show = [0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B_ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'No_Show': [0.1,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.6],
                   'Session': ['s1','s1','s1','s2','s2'],
                   'slot_num': [1,2,3,1,2],
                   'Cumulative_no_show': [1.5, 0.4, 1.6, 0.3, 1.9]
                   })
df = df[['B_ID', 'No_Show', 'Session', 'slot_num', 'Cumulative_no_show']]
df['u_cumulative'] = df['Cumulative_no_show']

print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
   B_ID  No_Show Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show  u_cumulative
0     1      0.1      s1         1                 1.5           1.5
1     2      0.1      s1         2                 0.4           0.4
2     3      0.3      s1         3                 1.6           1.6
3     4      0.5      s2         1                 0.3           0.3
4     5      0.6      s2         2                 1.9           1.9
```

then:

```
def Insert_row(row_number, df, row_value):
    # Starting value of upper half
    start_upper = 0

    # End value of upper half
    end_upper = row_number

    # Start value of lower half
    start_lower = row_number

    # End value of lower half
    end_lower = df.shape[0]

    # Create a list of upper_half index
    upper_half = [*range(start_upper, end_upper, 1)]

    # Create a list of lower_half index
    lower_half = [*range(start_lower, end_lower, 1)]

    # Increment the value of lower half by 1
    lower_half = [x.__add__(1) for x in lower_half]

    # Combine the two lists
    index_ = upper_half + lower_half

    # Update the index of the dataframe
    df.index = index_

    # Insert a row at the end
    df.loc[row_number] = row_value

    # Sort the index labels
    df = df.sort_index()

    # return the dataframe
    return df

walkin_count = 1
skip = False
last_Session = ''
i = 0
while True:
    row = df.loc[i]
    if row['Session'] != last_Session:
        walkin_count = 1
    last_Session = row['Session']

    values_to_append = ['walkin{}'.format(walkin_count), walkin_no_show[i],
                        row['Session'], row['slot_num'], row['Cumulative_no_show'], (1 - walkin_no_show[i])]

    if row['Cumulative_no_show'] > 0.8:
        df = Insert_row(i+1, df, values_to_append)
        walkin_no_show.insert(i+1, 0)
        walkin_count += 1
        i += 1
    i += 1
    if i == df.shape[0]:
        break
print(df)
```

output:

```
      B_ID  No_Show Session  slot_num  Cumulative_no_show  u_cumulative
0        1      0.1      s1         1                 1.5           1.5
1  walkin1      0.3      s1         1                 1.5           0.7
2        2      0.1      s1         2                 0.4           0.4
3        3      0.3      s1         3                 1.6           1.6
4  walkin2      0.3      s1         3                 1.6           0.7
5        4      0.5      s2         1                 0.3           0.3
6        5      0.6      s2         2                 1.9           1.9
7  walkin3      0.3      s2         2                 1.9           0.7
```

I hope it helps.

The used function imported from: [Insert row at given position](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insert-row-at-given-position-in-pandas-dataframe/)

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my logic.. can you pls try by using my same input and replicate same expected output

Comment: @Danish, try it now!